# Prove that a strictly decreasing function has only one root in a given interval

Tags: analysis, roots

Let $G(s)$ be a function who is strictly monotonic decreasing in $s\in[0,1)$ with $G(0)>0$ and $G(1)=0$. How to prove that $s=1$ is the only root of the function in $s\in[0,1]$?

My problem in proving this is the following:

If the function would be strictly monotonic decreasing in $s\in[0,1]$ then with $a,b\in[0,1]$ and $a<b$

$G(a)>G(b)$ is true.

Then with b=1

$G(a)>G(1)=0$

so b=1 is the only root in [0,1].
Now my problem is that $G(s)$ is only strictly decreasing in $s\in[0,1)$ so I dont know why

$G(s)>G(1)=0$,

because 1 isnt in the intervall where $G(s)$ is strictly decreasing.

Comment: you should post what progress or attempts you have made. This prevents cheating a little, among other things. Also, welcome to MSE!

Comment: Thanks, i edited my comment and hope this is fine now.

Answer (score -1):

Let $s<1.$ The definition of strictly decreasing is that if $b>a,$ then $G(b)<G(a).$
Therefore, $G(1)<G(s),$ or in other words $G(s) > 0,$ meaning $s$ is not a root of $G.$

Comment: But $G(s)$ is only strictly decreasing in [0,1). So $G(1)<G(s)$ for $s\in [0,1)$ isnt always true.

Comment: @MathAccount12 It's not true unless the function is continuous.

Comment: So for $x\in[0,1)$,$G(x)>lim_{x \to 1^-}G(x)=G(1)=0$, where the first step follows from the decreasing property of $G(x)$ and the first equality because $G(x)$ is continuous.